# Not able to configure IIS 7 for ASP.NET 3.5 app

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-3.5

I developed a small ASP.NET 3.5 app. with only few pages and no DB connectivity. I am trying to publish it, but my website gives error:

```
**Parser Error Message:** It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

**Source Error:**

Line 45:             
Line 46:         -->
Line 47:     <authentication mode="None"/>
Line 48:        <!--
Line 49:             The <customErrors> section enables configuration
```

I am using Windows 7 with IIS 7. When I add a new website in IIS there are a few concerns here. Below are the images that show that something is wrong underhood:

1. While creating new application pool for an application built on .NET 3.5, I could not see the .NET Framework 3.5 in the list:

[image]

2. When I open the Add Website dialog, and click Test Settings, it gives this error:

[image]

Please let me know how to fix this issue. I also want to know whether I have to add a website or add a virtual directory?

Comment: .net 3.5 is the same CLR as 2.0, so you do want to pick 2.0 on the application pool

Comment: I once selected that, still it fails in the next level.

Comment: is your website/vdir pointing as a network location?  there are some very convoluted rules on iis now, i have to google for fixes nearly everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the error message you provided, you have to have a virtual directory defined for your app with the pysical path pointing to your ASP.NET app folder, and also have the virtual dir as an application ("Convert to application" in the context menu of the virtual dir node, i think).

you dont need to create an app pool , but its probably a good idea.
also the registration issue that the guys here explain is also a must.

Comment: Ok, so finally it worked. I had to change few more things. While converting it to an application, instead of Pass-through authentication, I clicked "Connect As" and there I entered Windows 7 login credentials of the administrator user on which I was logged ON. Secondly, I turned off the Compilation Debug in the win.config file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register .Net framework for IIS using `aspnet_regiis -i`commmand?

Comment: I tried this command from the Command window, but it is not recognizing the syntax. It is not added in environment variables.

Comment: try to run it directly from %WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\

Comment: first you need to go to the .net framework installed directory using command prompt ex:-C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[.Net Version]

Comment: Done all that you suggested. run that command, restarted IIS, created VDir, again restarted IIS, Rebuilt solution, RePublished. Still the same error.